# Jenkins job trigger using webhook and manual

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have situation. I have configure single Jenkins job for more than 1 environment. But development environment , job should start automatically using webhook and for other using manual. So, any 1 working fine for me. Anyone know how to create such job? Or is it advisable to use 2 different job i.e. for manual and for automatic?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this scenario using two different approaches:

**Free style / Maven Jobs:**

Jenkins Build Pipeline plugin.

[Build Pipeline link](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin)

First we have to create a Jenkins job which will be triggered by web-hook. Then we need to create downstream jobs for each environment. We can trigger those downstream jobs either automatically or manually based on condition.

**Pipeline Jobs:**

You have add a step for manual interruption. So that it will wait for your approval to execute next steps.

[Jenkins Input Step for approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your objective by creating a pipeline. Create a job for your development environment and configure it using github webhook, other job you can mention it under builds other projects option in your development jobs configuration. This will create a pipeline of two jobs for you, and first one will get triggered automatically as required. You can select on what instance you want second one to run under build other project.

Other way is to have your second project job as parameterized one, so it wont be triggerd unless you pass it some values (you will have to use trigger parameterized build option in your first jobs config).

Simplest way just create pipeline of two jobs as said, and disable the second one. You can trigger it manually by enabling it as u need.

I hope this will help you, feel free to contact in case of any queries.